# html input won't take input without left mouse button hold

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with the Kitchen sink script at [fabricjs.com](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/). I ran into a problem where I can't type anything in any inputs unless I hold the left mouse button down. You can see how it's appearing by trying to type a canvas color into the Canvas near the top. I tested in FX, and IE. Chrome gives the windows color picker which is pretty cool. Not sure what's causing the issue as I tried another version of JQuery with the same result. WC3 validation didn't yield anything that would cause it either. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is with `paster.js`. Specifically lines 24-28:

```
// make sure it is always in focus
pasteCatcher.focus();
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    pasteCatcher.focus();
});
```

Which means that any time you click anywhere (including in your background colour input box), focus is immediately stolen by the `pasteCatcher`. Notice that you can use the keyboard to navigate to the input box and it all works fine until you actually click a mouse button.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! It was strange because I removed some of the html elements under the color input as a test and then it worked correctly. I removed the script. Thanks again.